# External HDDs don't appear until unplugged and plugged back in

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I'm trying to use my Ubuntu computer as a file/media server, and I have four removable HDDs plugged in.  After a fresh boot, two of them mount, or appear in fdisk or /dev/sd*, but they do appear in lsusb.  After I unplug them and plug them back in, they appear and mount fine.  I have usb_storage in /etc/modules, which was suggested somewhere, but it didn't help

My fstab:

```
UUID=4C10E94110E9329E /media/2TB auto noauto,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=C6026AF6026AEABF /media/3TB2 auto noauto,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=08A4462AA4461A98 /media/2TB2 auto noauto,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=18A2F5C4A2F5A682 /media/3TB fuseblk noauto,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

the 08... and 18... don't mount.  (I switched 3TB to fuseblk because manually mounting it with auto complained that I didn't specify a filesystem)

trying to mount them after boot with

```
mount /media/3TB -v
```

gives no output

lsblk:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   350M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 878.6G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  42.7G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0    10G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 931.5G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0   1.8T  0 part /media/2TB
sdd      8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0   2.7T  0 part /media/Videos3TB
```

Comment: Are the drives "permanently" assigned to your Ubunutu box, or do you move them about between systems? If they stay with your Ubuntu system, adding entries for them in your `fstab` file to auto-mount them might fix the problem. Also, does this happen with all USB devices or just the drives?

Comment: they are.  I added all four to my fstab, and now two work, and two error on boot, asking me if I want to wait for them to become available or skip them.  The two that work and the two that didn't have the same USB IDs: Seagate RSS LLC FreeAgent GoFlex Desk USB 3.0 and Seagate RSS LLC FreeAgent GoFlex Desk respectively.  my usb keyboard works fine, and a flash drive I plugged in before booting showed up fine.

Comment: (although all four are USB 3.0 drives?)

Comment: All are connected on USB 3.0 ports or through a USB 3.0 hub? And what mount point did you set in `fstab`? Typical is to mount them in /media/

Comment: And can you edit your question with the `fstab` entries?

Comment: They're all in USB3 ports on my motherboard.  I used gnome-disks to generate the fstab settings, and it made the weird /mnt/UUID names, however they also get mounted to /media/<username>/<partition name> somehow

Comment: Yeah, change the mount point to /media/somename for each and change them to `noauto` to delay mounting them until login.

Comment: even if they have noauto they'll still automount at login?

Comment: Yes, the `noauto` delays mounting until login rather than as the kernel modules load. Worst case is they will show up in the Devices list from which you can mount them.

Comment: I changed the mountpoint and noauto, and now the two work like before, and the other two give no error on boot (as expected, since they're not being mounted yet), and give no error anywhere else, and don't show up in /dev/sd* for fdisk.  (see extra comment in post also)

Comment: `sudo umount /media/{volume label}` then remove the `auto` statements from `fstab` then `sudo mount -a`

Comment: sudo umount /media/3TB : not mounted.  sudo mount -a -v: nothing was mounted.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I was reading the first `auto` statement in the wrong context - i.e. not as the filesystem type. If you know the partitioning scheme (ext4, ntfs) enter it there or continue to use `auto`. (Disk Utility can show the partitioning scheme for unmounted drives.) External drives or partitions not set up during installation or managed by a bootloader won't show as devices in /dev/sd* or /mnt- they are set to mount to /media.

Comment: I don't have a 'Disk Utility' program.  I have 'Disks', which doesn't show the two missing drives at all.  trying to manually mount a drive with its UUID gives "mount: no such partition found".

Comment: Output of `lsblk`?

Comment: added to the post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13482/discussion-between-douggro-and-zacaj)